# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

Object destructuring throws error in case of null object is passed

```js
function test ({name= 'empty'}={}) {
  console.log(name)
}
test(null);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>       at test (:1:15)
>       at :1:1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: default arguments are only assigned when the input parameter is `undefined`. `null` is not the same as `undefined`.

Answer (score 47):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

> Default function parameters allow named parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

In other words, the default parameter will *not* be assigned if `null` gets passed:

```js
function fn(arg = 'foo') {
  console.log(arg);
}
fn(null);
```

Destructure in the first line of the function instead:

```js
function test (arg) {
  const { name = 'empty' } = arg || {};
  console.log(name)
}
test(null);
```

Comment: Instead of `const { name = 'empty' } = arg || {};`, you can default `arg` to `{}` in the function params `function test (arg = {})`, and then remove the `|| {}` from the destructuring statement `const { name = 'empty' } = arg`;

I personally find this easier to read and a bit cleaner.

Comment: The problem is that default arguments *do not trigger* when `null` is passed (see first snippet).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any arguments or a value assigned to the object,but want to pass it empty because you plan on assigning it a value at a later stage,Its best to pass it empty by not placing it inside parenthesis.

So lets suppose you have :

This function :

```
const {signup}  = useAuth()
```

This will definitely throw an error because you are essentially passing the object with no arguments.

To fix this,you would have to remove the empty object from parenthesis as follows:

```
const signup  = useAuth()
```

then use it in your class or function thereafter as follows:

```
async {....
     await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)

...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test (user = {}) {
  const defaultName= 'Invalid User Object'
  if(!user?.name) return defaultName
  const {name} = user
  return user
}
test(null);
```

Answer (score -5):

This is what you need:

```js
function doDotsCalculations(el) {
    const height = el.height();
    const {top = 'empty', left = 'empty'} = el.position() || {};
    const res = height + top + 20;

    $(".owl-carousel .owl-dots").css({
        top: `${res}px`,
        left: `${left}px`
    });
}
```